# How can I pass the table name as an argument

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have this code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tablepass12]
    (@TableName nvarchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)

    SELECT @SQL = 'SQLCMD -S ICB3110\SQLEXPRESS -d teena -E -Q "SELECT * FROM "'+@TableName+' -o d:\processing\'+@TableName+'.csv' 

    EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @SQL
END;
```

When execute it, I get this error

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Server ICB3110\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'AIR_LINE
>       '.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server ICB3110\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'AIR_LINE
>       '.

Comment: How do you call the procedure? unless you do tricks with the quotes in the tablename variable your generated select has extra quotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error states:

> Unclosed quotation mark

Your string is:

```
'SQLCMD -S ICB3110\SQLEXPRESS -d teena -E -Q "SELECT * FROM "'+@TableName+' -o d:\processing\'+@TableName+'.csv'
```

Once the `@TableName` variable is replaced with its value, the string gets rendered as:

```
'SQLCMD -S ICB3110\SQLEXPRESS -d teena -E -Q "SELECT * FROM "AIR_LINE -o d:\processing\AIR_LINE.csv'
```

If you look at the `-Q` parameter, it is malformed as:

```
"SELECT * FROM "AIR_LINE
```

You just need to move the double-quote (`"`) to the other side of the variable (it should be to the left of the `-o`, not to the right of the `FROM`):

```
'SQLCMD -S ICB3110\SQLEXPRESS -d teena -E -Q "SELECT * FROM '+@TableName+'" -o d:\processing\'+@TableName+'.csv'
```